# Problem with twitter API: cannot update status

Tags: javascript, api, twitter

I am trying to create Google Chrome extension that will send interesting links to twitter. But, I am unable to connect to the Twitter. The server gets my request, but the response is always the same: "You do not have permission to access /1/statuses/update.json on this server (403 Forbidden)." I am using Wireshark to inspect Http responses. Here is the code of the function i am using:

```
function setStatus(msg) {
var status = "status="+msg;
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open("POST","http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json");
client.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic <user credentials>");
client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
client.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(client.readyState ==4){
            //whatever
        }
    }
client.send(status);
```

Am I doing something wrong? I am using Basic Auth. I use [this tool](http://ostermiller.org/calc/encode.html) to do the encoding, and just put the result instead of "user credentials" part. Also, can someone give me an example of OAuth?

Comment: do you use client.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode("user:password")); ? (the colon is important ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already posted what was the problem, but for some reason, that post is missing. Nevermind, here is what happened:
The code sample I gave in the first post was correct, but I made a mistake in the manifest file. The manifest file contains the "permissions" section - I needed to list all of the links that extension was going to use. I forgot to list "http://api.twitter.com" and that was the problem. When I added that link, everything started working. Thanks for suggestions and responses.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`/account/verify_credentials`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/account/verify_credentials) to check your authentification first, you might did some mistakes with the encoding, or the password is simply wrong.

Comment: I tried your solution - I am still getting 403 response code. Either I am constantly making some mistake with authentication header, or something else is wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to do:

```
client.open("POST","https://screen_name:password@api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json");
```

and not worry about changing the request headers.